# Facebook required access Token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My application in `JavaScript` identified users by `facebook id`. Send request to server with ID and `access Token`, how server (Java EE) can check is this client use right user token ?

Comment: How is the client getting this access token?

Comment: FB.getLoginStatus( function(response) {
accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
});

Comment: If you are getting an access token directly from Facebook you don't need to check anything on the server - you can trust that Facebook provided the user with the correct token.

Comment: yes, but when someone, can send the post to server, must be identified, becouse another client can use someone else Facebook ID and random access token.

Comment: Access tokens are generated per application and per user. Only the user that was provided that token will be able to use it. Facebook already thought of these issues and prevent it as part of their validation. It is not something that us developers need to worry about :)

Comment: What you should do, is wrap your server code with a sort of `try..catch` statement so that if a user does send a funny token ,the server will be able to handle it and will not crash.